# Android: App crashes on the device while uploading images,java.lang.outofMemoryError

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-image

In my android application I have to allow the user to click a button to open the Gallery and to select an image. And then needs to load that specific selected image to an Image View in my layout(UI). and i have some code but it comes java.lang.outofmemory.Please anyone can help me?

Comment: The bitmaps you're loading might be too big for the amount of memory available on your test device. Alternatively, you might be loading too many bitmaps into the gallery at a time. People often run in to this, you have to put some forethought into your code when dealing with bitmaps on Android. Here's a presentation by Romain Guy that touches on this topic: https://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/Th_0230_TurboChargeYourUI-HowtomakeyourAndroidUIfastandefficient.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should decode the image uri on onActivityResult() method.
Call this method to decodeBitmap.

```
/**
     * This is very useful to overcome Memory waring issue while selecting image
     * from Gallery
     * 
     * @param selectedImage
     * @param context
     * @return Bitmap
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    public static Bitmap decodeBitmap(Uri selectedImage, Context context)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;

        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                break;
            }
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);
    }
```

For more details go though the topic **Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently**

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Hope this Help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find why you get this exception and how to correctly display bitmaps: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html